# how to add form id in cakephp when creating a form

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

i am new in cakephp so i dont know how can i do this ..

i want to add custom form id in my form but it is not adding the id ..it is using the default   one  adding the 'UserIndexForm' id..
how can i add this id 
i want to do like this

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form-login">
```

here cakephp code

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
'inputDefaults' => array(
    'label' => false,
    'div' => false,
    'id' =>'form-login'//not working

)
  ));

?>
```

please help me if anyone know this
 thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inputDefaults option is only changing the input fields so you need to set the id on the root level of the array:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
'id' => 'form-login',
'inputDefaults' => array(
    'label' => false,
    'div' => false

)
  ));

?>
```